# Openscad "flower" from hexagons

Tags: openscad

I want to make a "flower" from hexagons in OpensCAD (like in the photo inserted, but without the center one, only that 6 around). I think that it has to be done with for loop, but i don't really understand how.

Im trying to make a grid from hexagons, but without the center one.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
R=10;
h=1;
gap=1;
for(i=[0:60:359])
    rotate([0,0,i]) translate([0, R*sqrt(3)+gap,0]) cylinder(r=R, h=h, $fn=6);
```

[image]

The main trick here is that a cylinder with `$fn=6` is an hexagon.

The rest (translating first, then rotating around z axis) is the same as my answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76743793/openscad-holes-in-cylinder-around-the-center-but-rotated). I expect you've read my explanations there, even tho I never got any feedback.